# C# XAML get button in searchbar which removes input

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a searchbar in my app. When i enter text i want a cancel button to appear inside the searchbar. Can i do this by just dropping a button on top of my searchbar or is there a better way to do it?

this is my searchbar:

```
<SearchBox x:Name="sbSearch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" QuerySubmitted="SearchBox_QuerySubmitted" SearchHistoryEnabled="False"/>
```

and this is what i want: *note the code behind this searchbox is not mine.

[image]

I only need help to let the button appear (either drag it onto the searchbar or there might there be a property i can't find?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look here http://davidowens.wordpress.com/2009/02/18/wpf-search-text-box/ It seems that is exactly what you need.

Comment: i'm not using wpf. but maby it works, ill try. Thanks for your response!